# Best way to generate an ordered series from one or several columns of pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
Name    Day    Earnings
Aaron    1      100
Aaron    3      250
Aaron    4      125
Bill     2      55
Bill     3       62
Bill     5       1000
```

So that I'd like to end up with:

```
Name         Series
Aaron       [1:100, 2:0, 3:250, 4:125]
Bill        [1:0, 2:55, 3:62, 4:0, 5:1000]
```

Can I do this with a simply old apply and groupby (if so I can't see to find the right combo)? Or is there a better way?

So far the closest I can get is:

```
>>> for Name, Info in df.groupby('Name'):
...    print(zip(Info['Day'], Info['Earnings']))
... 
[(1, 100), (3, 250), (4, 125)]
[(2, 55), (3, 62), (5, 1000)]
```

Here's a csv I used to generate the data frame:

```
Name,Day,Earnings
Aaron,1,100
Aaron,3,250
Aaron,4,125
Bill,2,55
Bill,3,62
Bill,5,1000
```

Comment: Could you put the dataframe as Python code, so one could run it?

Comment: @roadrunner66 thanks for your comment. How can I put it as Python code? I included a csv format above.

Comment: may i ask you why do you want to have it this way? It may lead you to lots of problems when working with such a structures. Just my 2 cents...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import re
import itertools

names = '''Aaron    1      100
Aaron    3      250
Aaron    4      125
Bill     2      55
Bill     3       62
Bill     5       1000'''

print [(n,  map(lambda x: '%s:%s'%(x[1],x[2]), l))
 for n, l in itertools.groupby(
    [re.split('\W+', l)
     for l in names.split('\n')], lambda x: x[0])]
```